# Maximum external monitors supported by A1418?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt

I have an A1418, Late 2012 version and I'm having trouble locking down an answer to how many external monitors it can support. Right now I have the iMac and two external monitors via the two Thunderbolts. The monitors are non-Apple, non-Thunderbolt.

Is there any way I can add an additional two monitors? Can the A1418 support a total of 4 external monitors? Some sites say yes, others say no. What say you?

Comment: A1418 covers too many machines for anyone to be specific - [Everymac search](http://www.everymac.com/search/search.html?cx=partner-pub-8015755554271706%3A2hojc0-6s67&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=A1418&sa=Search&siteurl=www.everymac.com%2F&ref=&ss=0j0j1)

Comment: @Tetsujin I have made an update to my question, I have an A1418, Late 2012 version, which I think was one of the earliest A1418 made

Answer (score 1):

Two external displays with a resolution of 2560x1600

Resolution comes from the [specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP665?locale=en_US).
Number of displays comes from this [KB Article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154)